# Android call function in parent of SearchActivity

Tags: android, search, android-activity

i want to call a function on the parent of the search activity when a search result is clicked. How can i do that? (Can i pass a reference of the parent to the search activity for an interface? Or is there any possibility to start the search activity for a result? Or is it possible to start the search in the parent activity?)

```
...
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".search.SearchAllActivity"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
<activity
        android:name=".search.SearchAllActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_search"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

The MainActivity triggers the search. The search is done and the results are displayed in the SearchAllActivity.

Edit:
One obvious solution (to obvious for me) would be to set setOnQueryTextListener and start the search manually:

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(mContext, SearchAllActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("query", mSearchView.getQuery());

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

In SearchAllActivity:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String query = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("query").toString();

        SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this, suggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, suggestionProvider.MODE);
        suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);

        runSearch(query);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

But now the suggestionsprovider is not working

Answer (score 0):

Call Search Activity Like This

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
```

After Searching add below code to send result to MainActivity

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity
```

To Catch Result from SearchActivity in MainActivity add below code in MainActivity

```
@Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

Comment: that is something i would like to do, but the problem is, that the SearchActivity is started, when the user pressed enter in the searchview. So i don't know how/when/where to start the activity with 'startActivityFoResult(intent, requestcode)'